# How do I allow remote access to mysql using xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp, navicat

I'm using xampp and navicat to manage mysql on two dev machines (laptop & desktop). The laptop is my main machine, while the desktop acts as a local dev server for the group.

Connecting to mysql via localhost in navicat is working fine on the laptop. Is there a way (other than the http tunneling method) to allow access to the desktop from the laptop via navicat?

Comment: What OS -- Linux? Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure that your mysql is binding to a socket on 0.0.0.0 and you should be able to connect to that socket. I guess the default is for mysql to bind to 127.0.0.1, which, of course, is hard to reach from the outside.

EDIT:
The MySQL configuration file [should be](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1172) in `.\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`. You need to find the `bind-address` parameter and change it to 0.0.0.0.

Everyone on your network should then be able to connect that MySQL instance. Of course, that may include people who better shouldn't do that. But as long as there is a password for each mysql user and the instance is not facing the internet, there is not much to worry about.

Comment: Any idea where I adjust that? Any security issues I ned to worry about?

Comment: I assumed you had at least some knowledge about MySQL configuration. Sorry. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If not found, add it.

bind-address=0.0.0.0 under mysqld

See it
http://www.afella.org/mysql/my.ini

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is easier and quick:

1. Go to PhpMyAdmin and then:
   `localhost/phpmyadmin -> User accounts -> Edit privileges -> Login Information`
2. Change `Host name` drop down to `Any host` or type any IP `192.168.0.3` or even with masking `192.168.0.%` And click the button `Go`.

[image]
3. Restart MySQL

More details [here](https://www.hacking-tutorial.com/tips-and-trick/how-to-make-xampp-mysql-database-accessible-by-network/). You can delete the newly created row after your purpose will be solved.